# Insert into DataArray at specific coordinate

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am trying to populate a DataArray with some meta information about cells to add it to a Dataset.

```
airtemps = xr.tutorial.load_dataset('air_temperature')
airtemps = airtemps.sel(time=slice('2013-01-01', '2013-12-31'))
```

I can set an entire new set of data given the existing dimensions:

```
airtemps['some_data'] = ([ 'lat', 'lon'], np.random.rand(25,53))
```

What I would like is to add a single data point at a given coordinate, basically

```
airtemps.some_data.sel_points(lat=75., lon=200.) = "New data"
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work with `sel_points`, but instead of assignment with `.sel` you can use the `.loc` indexer, e.g.,

```
airtemps.some_data.loc[dict(lat=75., lon=200.)] = "New data"
```

Note that this will only work if the point `(lat=75., lon=200.)` already exists in `airtemps`. Xarray does not support inserting values at new coordinates, because this cannot be done efficiently with its NumPy based data structures. If you need to insert new values, you will need to create a new xarray data structure with appropriate values from scratch.

Comment: Thanks! Getting closer. Is there a way to included data with new coordinates (eg. lat=74.5)? (btw: Brilliant module you created there!)

Comment: @shoyer, Nice!  I always forget about the `loc` indexer method.

Comment: No, I'm afraid it's not possible to insert values at new coordinates. I updated my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this section](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html#indexing-with-labeled-dimensions) in the xarray docs. None of the `.sel` methods allow for assignment.

Any assignment should be done using normal indexing:

```
airtemps.some_data[dict(lat=0, lon=0)] = 4
```

There has been talk of extending xarray's ability to assign by coordinate label but we don't have that feature currently. Until then, we just have to come up with a label to index position mapping and then follow the syntax above.

Comment: Nah, the indexer doesn't like assignments unfortunately. I am missing a section in the likes of "data manipulation" in the docs which makes me think that this is not working the way I'd like.

Comment: @TomTom101 - I've updated my answer.  I should have replaced your floats with integer indexers in my first example.